Google Scripts can't authenticate with Microsoft Graph because AppFetchURL comes from a different server
I am working on a Google apps script that authenticates with Microsoft Graph. I can get an Access Token through https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/token, but this access token will always respond with invalid signature or unknown error: inner error. I spoke with someone in the Azure discord and they said it was because of AppFetchURL coming from a different server than what requested the token. How would I work around this?
Note: doPost(e) just runs api_todotest() so I didn't bother including it.
Note2: yes I know the commenting is a mess I was banging my head against my desk when I added those.
function api_todotest() {
  ACCESS_TOKEN = graphAuthenticatetest2();
  var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/REDACT/todo/lists/REDACT/tasks";
  var payload ={
    "title": "Task created from goog scripts",
  };
  var options = {
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
    "Header": {},
    "headers": {  
      "content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": ACCESS_TOKEN,

    },
    //"contentType": "application/json",
    "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload),
  };
  console.log("I used this access token :D : "+ACCESS_TOKEN);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  console.log(response.getContentText());
  return response;
}

function graphAuthenticatetest2() {
  var url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/token"
  var payload = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "REDACT",
    "scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    "client_secret": "REDACT",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
  };
  var options = {
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "method": "post",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "Header": {"grant_type": "client_credentials",},
    "headers": {  
      "content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    },
    "payload": payload,
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  console.log(response.getContentText());
  const graphtokens = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  console.log("Access Token: " + graphtokens['access_token']);
  var returnvar = graphtokens['access_token'].toString();
  console.log(typeof returnvar);
  console.log("made it past the new code :D")
  return graphtokens['access_token']
}

I tried testing different urls from the graph api and I also tried manually entering Access Tokens from the Graph Explorer, the manually entered tokens work a treat but these won't.
I was expecting an output similar to this:
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('REDACT')/todo/lists('REDACT')/tasks/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "REDACT",
    "importance": "normal",
    "isReminderOn": false,
    "status": "notStarted",
    "title": "testytest",
    "createdDateTime": "2024-05-12T19:46:12.9751365Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-05-12T19:46:13.0428779Z",
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "categories": [],
    "id": "REDACT",
    "body": {
        "content": "",
        "contentType": "text"
    }
}


Thank you for replying. From I tried the script with a known good access token form graph explorer again and the url works but I am not sure how to validate the access token., I think that the origin of your issue of this question is an invalid access token. In this case, I would like to recommend to update your question. I think that my proposed answer can be used when the access token is valid. So, in this case, I think that my answer is not useful for your current issue. So, I delete my answer.
